# Module federation with React & Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to setup a micro frontends project, when React will be the host with Angular remote app.

this is the webpack configs for both React & Angular:

Angular (the remote) `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.base.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "angularApp",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "angularApp",
        library: { type: "var", name: "angularApp" },
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './Module': './apps/angular-app/src/app/app.module.ts'
        },

        // For hosts (please adjust)
        // remotes: {
        //     "reactApp": "http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js",

        // },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

React (the host) `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const {composePlugins, withNx} = require('@nrwl/webpack');
const {withReact} = require('@nrwl/react');
const {ModuleFederationPlugin} = require('webpack').container;
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.base.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), withReact(), (config) => {
  // Update the webpack config as needed here.
  // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`
  config.plugins = [
    ...config.plugins,
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'reactApp',
      remotes: {
        angularApp: 'angularApp@http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},
        "@angular/common": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},
        "@angular/common/http": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},
        "@angular/router": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto'},
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })
    }),
  ];

  return config;
});
```

and this is the React `app.tsx`

```
import React from "react";

// @ts-ignore
const AngularApp = React.lazy(() => import("angularApp/Module"));

export function App() {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback='Loading DaleAngularComponent'>
      <AngularApp></AngularApp>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Im getting this error message when running the React app (`remoteEntry.js` exists but something is wrong there):

```
ScriptExternalLoadError
Loading script failed.
(missing: http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js)
while loading "./Module" from 6142
```

[image]

**I tried** `library.type` of `var`, `global`, `module`, `udm` but nothing helped me.

both project are new so there is no spacial code there.

Answer (score 1):

This example here helped me:

https://github.com/harshmons/micro-front-end-react-application

It has react host that is loading Angular 13 module, Vue, React components using Module federation